# Need regex pattern to get everything in between

Tags: java, regex, string

From this String I need to get authorization value but without [\" and \"]

```xml
[\"bla bla bla\"],\"x-user-id\":[\"\"],
\"accept\": [\"application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01\"],
\"original-path\": [\"/test/test\"],
\"authorization\":[\"Bearer dadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadad\"],
\"requestUrl\":\"/test/test/test\",\"host\":[\"test.com\"]
```

I have tried with `\[(.*?)\\]` and it return all values between [].

Any suggestion?

Comment: What about `authorization\\":\[(.*?)\]` ?

Comment: I need just a value I got: "authorization\":[\"Bearer dadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadad\"] and i need just Bearer dadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadad

Comment: Share the java code, you need to use another Regex method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add the word `authorization` in the pattern to get only the one `authorization\\":\[\\"(.*?)\\"]`

```
String value = "[\\\"bla bla bla\\\"],\\\"x-user-id\\\":[\\\"\\\"],\\\"accept\\\":[\\\"application/json, text/javascript, /; q=0.01\\\"],\\\"original-path\\\":[\\\"/test/test\\\"],\\\"authorization\\\":[\\\"Bearer dadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadad\\\"],\\\"requestUrl\\\":\\\"/test/test/test\\\",\\\"host\\\":[\\\"test.com\\\"]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("authorization\\\\\":\\[\\\\\"(.*?)\\\\\"]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // Bearer dadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadadad
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/\\"authorization\\":\[\\"(.+?)\\"]/
```

This should do the trick, the first capturing group (ie. `Matcher.group(0)`) will contain the value without any of the fluff around it.